# HTTP to HTTPS Redirect Exception

Tags: http, redirect, https, web-config, rule

I'm using a HTTP to HTTPS redirect in my MVC application.

This is the code that I'm using in Web.config:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
  </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

There is a page in my application that doesn't work on HTTPS, so I need to add an exception to this rule.

I was wondering if anyone can help me on that or show me some tutorials/examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add another condition that negates the rule for your url. Your new rule would be something like this:

```
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          <add input="{R:1}" pattern="myfolder\/myfile\.aspx" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
      </rule>
```